# How to get Fips code of county from geolocator and geocode in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The below code gets the coordinates and the location. But I don't know how to get county fips
code from this.

```
Future<void> getUserLocation() async {
    currentPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude);

      place = placemarks[0];
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```